# What's the name of the song in Fred Bonaparte's level?

Tags: game-music-identification, psychonauts

While fighting alongside Fred against Napoleon, there's music playing that seems like a part of a classical composition. What's its name? Has it been composed for the game or is it part of a previous work?

Comment: It’s annoying that neither the 21-track “Psychonauts OST” nor the 18-track “Psychonauts Score” contain this track. I’ve only found it on a 33-track album that sites can’t agree on the name of – probably someone ripped that album from the game files. [Search for the names of its tracks](https://www.google.com/search?q=Psychonauts+OST+Napoleon's+Final+Conflict+Revisited+Agent+Cruller's+Sacred+Hall) to find download links.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the song is *"Napoleon's Final Conflict Revisited."*

It has taken parts from Tchaikovsky's *1812 Overture* hence the classical composition, so in fact has been both composed for this game a bit as well as being part of a previous work.

You can find the music for the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiRqRfGPMcU) which also tells you all about the piece in the description:

Comment: Here are the copied parts of 1812 Overture: [3:17](http://youtu.be/N0cpKzDoOdA?t=3m17s), [8:06](http://youtu.be/N0cpKzDoOdA?t=8m6s), and the reprises of those sections later.